# hide value Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a method to display the keys and values. It also displays  **id**,  but I wish not to display it. Is there a filter method that would allow me to not display the id?

I use table from angular material.

Thanks in advance.
(I am a beginner)

**components.ts**

```
 makeRowObservable() {
        return this.service.get().pipe( map(data: myInterface[]) => data.toto.map((item: any[]) => this.transormListToMap())
    }
    
    transormListToMap() {
    
        let result = {};
    
        for (let i = 0; i < this.tableCols.length; i++) {
            let col = this.tableCols[i];
            let value = item[i];
            let colId = col.key;
            filter(key => result !== 'id'); // not work why ?
            result[colId] = value;
        }
        
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I took the liberty to format your code and also to make your question readable (punctuation, capital letters, and separated your block of text into three different sentences). Now your `makeRowObservable()` method is clearly invalid. Not only is it missing a closing parenthesis, but `map(data: interface) =>` is not the correct syntax for [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map). This code certainly isn't even compiling at all.

Comment: everything works fine as i copied my code by hand there are errors stackoverflow is not known to be a good code editor. i will be more careful next time. in my case i am looking for a way not to display ID

Comment: Can you put your code on http://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: nop i can't sorry, but i updated my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do following:

```
// ...
if (colId !== 'id') {
    result[colId] = value
}
// ...
```